# Gulp V4.0.0 'gulp start' is not a function

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have this below gulpfile.js. When i run the app using 'gulp start' then it is showing start is not a function.
Glup-cli version i'm using V4.0.0

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

const scripts = require('./scripts');
const styles = require('./styles');

// Some pointless comments for our project.

var devMode = false;

gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(styles)
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src(scripts)
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('build', function() {
    gulp.start(['css', 'js', 'html'])
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        open: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist',
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('start', function() {
    devMode = true;
    gulp.start(['build', 'browser-sync']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/css/**/*.css'], ['css']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/js/**/*.js'], ['js']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/templates/**/*.html'], ['html']);
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`gulp.start` has been deprecated in v4. Depending on your needs, you can use `gulp.series` or `gulp.parallel` instead.

```
- gulp.task('start', function() {
-   devMode = true;
-   gulp.start(['build', 'browser-sync']);
+ gulp.task('start', gulp.series('build', 'browser-sync'), function(done) {
+   devMode = true;
    gulp.watch(['./src/css/**/*.css'], ['css']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/js/**/*.js'], ['js']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/templates/**/*.html'], ['html']);
  });
```

This question is probably a duplicated of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986454/migrate-gulp-start-function-to-gulp-v4), but since that question hasn't got an accepted answer I'll just echo Mark's answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Derek said, in v4 of gulp you have to use gulp.series or gulp.parallel;

Another differences for v4 is that you need to explicit when the task is done, you have 6 ways to do it.. I'll link this answer for a really good explanation [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async)

Mohamed explanation might be useful to understand in depth the reasons, you can find both:  [Migrate gulp.start function to Gulp v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986454/migrate-gulp-start-function-to-gulp-v4)

I have tried the solution but it needed more code, so I will write my main changes here:

```
gulp.task("build",
    gulp.series(gulp.parallel("css", "js", "html"), function (done) {
        done();
    })
);


  gulp.task("start", gulp.series("build", "browser-sync"), function (done) {
      devMode = true;
      gulp.watch(["./src/css/**/*.css'"], ["css"]);
      gulp.watch(["./src/js/**/*.js"], ["js"]);
      gulp.watch(["./src/templates/**/*.html"], ["html"]);
   done();
});
```

in all of the other task, I simply added the *done()* function ( with the exception of the task html because it has a return that already explicit when the task is done)

Hope this will help someone else, have a nice day :)